# Online IQ test progressive matrix - circles, squares, and lines together

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

This question comes from an [online IQ test](https://hr.iq-test.cc/). This is the question:
[image]
I cannot find the logic behind this puzzle. Any help in this problem would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is the top right option because the pattern for each row is that you make the shape in the left column and middle column overlap and the parts that overlap produces the final shape in the third column.